# CentOS7のmailコマンドで外部メールアドレスあてにE-mailを送信するには

Tags: centos

#### 【質問の主旨】

CentOS7（「さくらのVPS」）のmailコマンドで外部メールアドレスあてにメールが送信できません。どうすれば外部メールアドレス宛にE-mailを送信できるようようになるでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

送信できないメールアドレスの例

```
# mail "Test mail" "hoge@gmail.com"
# mail "Test mail" "fuga@example.com"
```

gmailの他にも、自分が保有しているメールサーバのアドレスや、知人が保有しているメールサーバのアドレスも試してみました。おそらく全ての外部サーバへ送信することができないと思います

2.

1.で送信できなかった時の記録の一部は以下の通りです。

```
# view /var/log/maillog
Mar 10 16:47:57 os*********** postfix/smtp[3854]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.179.26]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 10 16:47:57 os*********** postfix/smtp[3854]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4003:c09::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 10 16:47:57 os*********** postfix/smtp[3854]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c1d::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 10 16:47:57 os*********** postfix/smtp[3854]: 38DAB57D07: to=<hoge@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=395248, delays=395188/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c1d::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

3.

受信できるメールアドレスの例

```
# mail "Test mail" "root@localhost"
```

メールアドレスのドメインを`localhost`にすると受信できました。
受信状況は下記の通りです。

```
# mail "Test mail" "root@localhost"
Subject: Test
.
EOT
Null message body; hope that's ok

# view /var/spool/mail/root
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp>
Received: by ***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id CB60A57D07; Mon, 11 Mar 2019 11:31:36 +0900 (JST)
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 11:31:36 +0900
To: root@localhost.vs.sakura.ne.jp,
        mail@***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp,
        Test@***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp
Subject: Test
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-Id: <20190311023136.CB60A57D07@***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp>
From: root@***********.vs.sakura.ne.jp (root)
```

4.

「さくらのVPS」はCentOS7を使用しています。

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Comment: `localhost`宛ての「受信できました」も、`Content-Description: Undelivered Message`になっているので、実際には「送信できずにエラーで返ってきた」メールじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: cubickさん。コメントありがとうございます。Taichi Yanagiyaさんのコメントでご指摘いただいたとおり、当該「さくらのVPS」はお試し期間中でした。cubickさんがおっしゃるように、`root@localhost`にも届いていないと思われます。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outbound 25番ポートへの接続が制限されているようです。
「さくらのVPS」のお試し期間中ではないでしょうか？

https://vps.sakura.ad.jp/flow/
の「お試し期間中の制限」参照

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさん。コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘のとおり、当該「さくらのVPS」は「お試し期間中」でした。さくらインターネットとの契約を「お試し期間」から「本契約」に変更したのちに再度`mail`コマンドを実行すると、自分が指定したメールアドレスにメールが送信されました。アドバイス助かります。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。